# Coldfusion RegEx replace html characters like &nbsp;

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I currently have code to remove html from a string:

```
<cfset arguments.textToFormat = REReplaceNoCase(arguments.textToFormat,"<[^>]*>","","ALL") />
```

However, this does not remove html characters like `&nbsp;`

What Regex could I use to ReReplace these characters??

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For removing &nbsp; and other similar strings :

`&[^;]+?;`

HTH